# How to set month Column width in AnyGantt?

Tags: gantt-chart, column-width, anychart

Is it possible to change the width of month column in AnyGantt from AnyChart ?

[This how my table look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2r4fR.png)

```
anychart.onDocumentReady(function() {
      // create data tree on our data
      var treeData = anychart.data.tree(getData(), anychart.enums.TreeFillingMethod.AS_TABLE);

      // create resource gantt chart
      chart = anychart.ganttResource();

      // set container id for the chart
      chart.container("container");

      // set data for the chart
      chart.data(treeData);

      // set start splitter position settings
      chart.splitterPosition(200);

      // get chart data grid link to set column settings
      var dataGrid = chart.dataGrid();

      // initiate chart drawing
      chart.draw();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for zoom control?

```
chart.xScale().minimum(Date.UTC(2000, 1, 2));    
chart.xScale().maximum(Date.UTC(2000, 3, 6));

// Set zoom to range.
chart.zoomTo("week", 2, "firstDate");
```

https://api.anychart.com/7.14.3/anychart.charts.Gantt#zoomTo
https://playground.anychart.com/api/7.14.3/charts/anychart.charts.Gantt.zoomTo_set_asInterval-plain

Also, there are:

```
https://api.anychart.com/7.14.3/anychart.charts.Gantt#fitAll
https://api.anychart.com/7.14.3/anychart.charts.Gantt#zoomIn
https://api.anychart.com/7.14.3/anychart.charts.Gantt#zoomOut
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thanks. Is it possible to force to appear days in the timeline header? It only appears years and months